# Help with Fin Damage on my Betta

Tags: aquarium, fish

So in the past my betta's fin got snagged on a plant I learned should not have been in his tank at all.. This is my first fish and didn't realize that the only fake plats in the tank should be silk. He lost most of his upper fin from getting it snagged but it isn't growing back very well and it's been a long time..

I'm also not positive, but I think his underside fin may have gotten another tear so I'm not sure what's causing it? Is it fin rot? I was wondering if someone could look at my fish and possibly tell me if that's what it is and what I can do to help him out.. I feel so terrible...

The only other thing I can add to help is that I recently was forced to use higher pH water in his tank than I normally do, his nitrates were getting high but the kind of water I usually get put in the tank I couldn't get form the store because of the coronavirus, so I had to use my tap water and conditioner which is actually a lot higher than what I usually do, but I had no choice, I didn't want him to be in dirty water.. Please help :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Betta fish fin tear or rot?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18731/betta-fish-fin-tear-or-rot)

Comment: What's the nitrate level out of your tap? Personally, I would do lots of water changes and give lots of food and give it lots of time.

Comment: The nitrate of my tap water I hadn't considered even being a problem but I just checked it and it reads as 0